# Unity Camera.onprerender & Camera.onPreCull

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've been researching how to make certain players (both offline and online for consoles and PC) invisible to other players in Unity for both 2D and 3D. I know having a separate layer for each player and their camera isn't efficient or effective and I was looking for something better. After days of research I finally found these:

[Camera-onPreRender](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-onPreRender.html), [Camera-onPreCull](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-onPreCull.html), and [Making GameObejcts dynamically invisible](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1242646/make-gameobjects-dynamically-visibleinvisible-for.html)

But I'm still very confused.

Are the  `public void MyPreRender(Camera cam)` & `public void MyPreCull(Camera cam)` delegates or something and the Enable/Disable just changing the value of camera to exclude game objects listed in the function? If so shouldn't they be labeled as a delegate to work? If not how does this function change the value of what game objects should or shouldn't be culled/rendered?

Also would this work well for what I'm doing with little hit on performance and frame rate? The other person said it did but does it really? Is there a better and faster way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `MyPreRender` and `MyPreCull` are delegates (or rather, a method that matches the signature of a defined delegate elsewhere). Specifically, they are Event Handler methods.

When the camera does a Render (or Cull) task, it first invokes all methods that have been subscribed to the PreRender (or PreCull) events (through the use of the `+=` to tell the other system about your handler method).

You can find out more about events from [this Unity tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events).